# Are questions relating to battery drills off topic

Tags: discussion

I need to drill out the holes on some sunon cooling fans as they are just that little bit too narrow.

I've been looking at various drills but cannot decide.  Most battery drills contain resistor/ electronics.

Are drills off topic and if so is there another stack to which I should go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're off-topic.  You might ask on the [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) site; they've got a [tools](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) tag.